# No module named beginner_tutorials.srv

Tags: ros, python, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m really new to ROS just started couple of days ago

i m following this Tuturial **(
ROS
Tutorials
WritingServiceClient(python)
)**

and i m getting this Error when i run the file with this command

"rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py
"

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/neo/ros_workspace/sandbox/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py", line 4, in 
from beginner_tutorials.srv import *
ImportError: No module named beginner_tutorials.srv
**

I have repeated the whole tutorial again and again Pls help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49997/no-module-named-beginner_tutorials.srv/) by [Neo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2306/neo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most probably you missed to adjust your CMakeLists.txt file
you have to uncomment
rosbuild_genmsg()
and
rosbuild_gensrv()

---

Originally posted by [anonymous3751](https://answers.ros.org/users/3751/anonymous3751/) with karma: 31 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was having this same problem. Your solution got me running. Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [atticdweller](https://answers.ros.org/users/3880/atticdweller/) with karma: 1 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1